# MYSQL LEFTJOIN multiple ids same table

Tags: mysql, left-join

Im trying to get a combination of ids from a table like this:

Table activation:

```
user_id    product_id reseller_id range_id  Name
-------------------------------------------------
1              1           5          2     Oscar
1              1           5          3     Luis
2              1           5          4     Julian
```

Table prices (compType_id = reseller_id):

```
 product_id     compType_id     price   range_id 
------------------------------------------------
1                   5           38.60      2
1                   5           48.60      3
1                   5           58.60      4
```

Table users:

```
 user_id    name
----------------
    1       lloyd
    2       Mark
```

I want to select the activation Name and the price of prices based on the user_id.
How can i do that?

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT a.name
(SELECT price FROM prices WHERE product_id = 1 AND range_id = 
AND compType_id = 5) AS price
FROM activation AS a
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.user_id = a.u_id
WHERE u.user_id = 1
```

The price columns have the same value in each row.

```
name    price   
Oscar   21.30
Luis    21.30
```

How can i change it to show the correct price?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with something like this:

```
SELECT a.company, a.name, a.email, a.phone, a.ruc, a.code, a.active,
a.numlic, (SELECT p.price FROM prices AS p WHERE p.product_id =
a.product_id AND p.range_id = a.range_id AND p.compType_id = c.type_id)
AS price
FROM activation AS a
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.user_id = a.u_id
LEFT JOIN companies AS c ON a.reseller_id = c.id
WHERE u.user_id = 1
```